Can I configure multiple timeouts for pgbouncer from my django settings?
I am trying to add pgbouncer to my architecture. I know that I can set various pgbouncer configuration settings in the pgbouncer.ini file. I want to replace postgresql with pgbouncer in my django settings, however, my django configuration currently uses different timeouts depending on the purpose of the connection.
For example, I want a longer timeout for connections intended to perform database migrations.
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        # <Other settings ...>
        "OPTIONS": {
            "options": f"-c statement_timeout={90 * 1000}",
        },
    },
    "migration": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        # <The same other settings as above ...>
        "OPTIONS": {
            "options": f"-c statement_timeout={120 * 1000}",
        },
    },
}


I have read the pgbouncer documentation and I 1haven't found anything that quite solves this problem.
